# Facebook SDK 'name' 漢字しか取得できない

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

```
let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, locale"])
```

上記のように、Facebookからプロフィール関連のデータを取得しています。
'name'や'first_name'、'last_name'のデータが漢字でしか取れません。
ローマ字で取得する方法はありますか？

'山田 太郎'というFacebookアカウントがあったとしたら、'Taro Yamada'のようにデータを取得したいのですが…。

'locale'を指定するようなのですが、Swiftでの指定の記述方法が分かっていません。
しょうもないことかもしれませんが、どうかお助けを…！

2016.1.23 追記

```
let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["locale": "en_US, ""fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, locale"])
```

のようにparamertersを指定しても結果は変わりませんでした。
ひょっとするとlocaleをコードで指定するのではなく、Facebookのアプリ管理ページとかで設定するのかな…。
引き続き回答を募集しております！

Comment: そもそもそのユーザーがローマ字名を設定していない、ということはないですよね？

Comment: そんあ事ってあるんですかねえ…。
テストしているユーザー（私のFacebookアカウント笑）を、iPhoneの言語設定を英語にした状態でFacebookアプリで見ると、ちゃんとローマ字になっています。一応設定でも見ましたが、ローマ字名はちゃんと登録されているようです。

Answer (score 1):

下記のようにすれば良いと思います。

```
let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["locale" : "en_US", "fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, locale"])
```

SwiftもFacebook SDKも学習中の身です。間違っていたらすいません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
そのparametersの指定でも、やはり日本人ユーザーは漢字で取れていまします。